# Get hash keys/values on same line as the function call

Tags: perl

Here is the code to reproduce the problem:

```
sub hello { return (h => 1, n => 1); }
print join ", ", values hello();
```

I get the error:

> Type of arg 1 to values must be hash
>   (not subroutine entry) at - line 4,
>   near ");" Execution of - aborted due
>   to compilation errors.

I know I can break the call and the print on two lines:

```
sub hello { return (h => 1, n => 1); }
my %hash = hello();
print join ", ", values %hash;
```

But I don't want to do that.   Is there some way to do this in one line so that I don't have to create temporary variables all the time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see the usefulness in a real program, but yes, it is possible.

```
print join ", ", values %{{hello()}};
```

Explanation: `hello()` is a list; `{hello()}` is a hash reference; `%{{hello()}}` is a hash.

Comment: It's useful in real programs all the time.  If you are getting returned a hash from an API and all you need are the keys or the values.

Comment: @tster: that's different. Certainly `%{sub_returning_hash()}` is useful. But the question is about a sub returning a plist (i.e., a list containing successions of keys and values), and that's not common in Perl.

Comment: A function which returns a hash is no different than a function which returns an array to the calling function.  Plus, functions which return hashes might be uncommon in your perl, but I deal with a lot of them.

Answer (score 9):

You could use hash references:

```
sub hello { return {h => 1, n => 1}; }
print join ", ", values %{hello()};
```

but otherwise, no. Perl may interpret the return value of a subroutine in either scalar or list context, but there is no concept of returning a value in a hash context.

---

**Update**: this also works

```
sub hello { return (h => 1, n => 1); }
print join ", ", values %{{hello()}};
```

The inner `{}` converts the output of `hello()` from a list into a hash reference.
The outer `%{}` dereferences the hash.

(Does `%{{}}}` count as a [pseudo-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897853/what-pseudo-operators-exist-in-perl-5)?)

Comment: +1 Later than my answer, but you took the time to write an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing that you could do is use a toggle variable.

```
sub hello { return (h => 1, n => 1); }
my $toggle = 1;
print join ", ", grep { $toggle = !$toggle; } hello();
```

Another thing you could do is use [`List::Pairwise`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Pairwise)

```
use List::Pairwise qw<mapp>;
print join ", ", mapp { $b } hello();
```

I had been looking for something to process a list of name-value pairs in a "stream" and even rolled my own, but then I found this on CPAN.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe this is possible because Perl is not strongly enough typed to know what subroutines return.

As far as Perl is concerned, all subroutines simply return LISTs (or a single SCALAR). LISTs can have certain operations applied to them (indexing, slicing, etc.), but nothing that requires an ARRAY variable (like `push`, `pop`, `shift`) or a HASH variable (including `keys`, `values`, `delete`, `exists`).

Hash assignment takes in a LIST as a parameter (which your function returns), and creates an associative hash with every odd element serving as a key to the next even element. Only after this assignment can it be called a HASH in Perl's grammar, and therefore only then will it be usable in the `values` function.