# Understanding strange Perl multiline comment mechanism

Tags: perl, operators, comments

EDIT: **Note to new Perl programmers**: This mechanism should NOT be used for multiline comments! It has a flaw decreases readability.

In this [PerlMonks post on mechanisms to produce multiline comments in Perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=100344), Abigail provided this one, that perplexes me:

> The problem with just using a here document is that it will issue a warning under '-w'. It's much better to use the little known << >> operator.

```
<<q=~q>>;
  This is a multiline comment.
q
```

Running it through `-M0=Deparse` gives:

```
"  This is a multiline comment.\n" =~ //;
-e syntax OK
```

Can someone tell me what is going on?

Comment: Wow, I feel sheepish! The answer was staring me in the face. The magician has you looking at the left hand (`<<`) and then its the right hand (`>>`) that fools you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Abigail's answer is partly humorous. There is in fact no `<< >>` operator (not in versions of Perl [before 5.22](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perl5220delta.pod#New-double-diamond-operator)), but there is a (not that well-known, I guess) `<<` operator. Not the binary shift operator, but the unary [here-document (heredoc for short)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%3c%3cEOF). A simple form of it is:

```
$long_string = <<EOF;
This is a long, multiline string.
It ends when EOF appears alone on a line.
It will be assigned to the \$long_string variable.
EOF
```

This is, in fact, the “multiline comment” feature underlying Abigail's answer — a multiline string literal. The rest is a bit of somewhat obfuscated Perl.

The bareword or quoted string after `<<` ends the string literal. You can use `q` as a bareword:

```
<<q;
This is a multiline comment, or rather a string literal whose value is ignored.
q
```

To understand the rest of Abigail's snippet, it helps to rewrite the here-document into a simple string literal:

```
"This is a multiline comment.\n" =~ q>>;
```

Ok, now `q>>` is the [`q` quote-like operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#q%2fSTRING%2f) with `>` as the delimiter character. `q>>` is equivalent to `''` (a non-interpolated literal, which happens to be empty). So the string literal is [matched against an empty pattern](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#The-empty-pattern-%2f%2f). The result of that matching is ignored anyway, but this clobbers the match result variables (`$1`, `$&`, etc).

Comment: Damn, beat me by 47 seconds. And that just because I was testing my program fragment to make sure I didn't typo. I'll give you +1 anyway, despite my bitterness. ;)

Comment: Of course I knew about the heredoc `<<`, I just can't believe I didn't see the `q{}` hidden in the `q>>`! WOW I feel sheepish. This whole thing, as I suspected it would, reminds me of the `-->` operator I've seen elsewhere `perl -E '$x=5;say $x while ($x --> 0);'`.

Comment: I should say that the `q` operator is not the regex quote operator (`qr`) but is rather the non-interpolating quote operator

Comment: I’ve lately been calling the `<<` operator *the hasta operator*, as in `<<"La_Vista"`.

Comment: There is a `<< >>` operator starting with Perl 5.22.

Comment: @mob Thanks for the notice. I don't have Perl 5.22 around here yet, does it break this code?

Answer (score 11):

Hah. There is no such thing as a "<< >>" operator. What's going on there is basically equivalent to this:

```
"" =~ ''
```

`=~` is, of course, the normal pattern-binding operator you normally use with `m//` or `s///`. The `''` is using the q{} syntax for literal strings, with `>` as a delimiter, and is interpreted as a pattern at run-time. The `""` is a here-doc with `q` as the terminating string.

I certainly wouldn't call this a comment though. Consider the output of this program fragment:

```
"copacetic" =~ q/(c[a-z]+)/;
print "$1\n";

<<q=~q>>;
    This is crap, not a comment!
q

print "$1\n";
```

Comment: after looking at my Deparse results I wondered if that wouldn't happen. I voted you up, other people should too! Too bad there can only be one correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The following isn't as pretty, but it results in no executable code.

```
0 && <<COMMENT
...
COMMENT
```

Comment: in the vein of tchrist, even better seems to be the pod format as comment command `=for comment` which is ignored by `perl` and `perldoc` (as well as other `pod` readers). However this wasn't really my question.