# Perl regex: remove everything (including line breaks) until a match is found

Tags: regex, perl

Apologies for the simple question. I don't clean text or use regex often.

I have a large number of text files in which I want to remove every line until my regex finds a match. There's usually about 15 lines of fluff before I find a match. I was hoping for a perl one-liner that would look like this:

```
perl -p -i -e "s/.*By.unanimous.vote//g" *.txt
```

But this doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: Including or excluding the line that matches?

Comment: Are those supposed to be literal `.` characters in `By.unanimous.vote`, or should they be escaped?

Comment: 1. The expression I posted only removes text that is before the match, but *on the same line*. It does not remove previous lines. 2. Not critical for my application, but I suppose we can erase the match too. 3. Literal `.` characters. They should not be escaped. Thanks all for looking into this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution using the [flip-flop operator](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlop#Range_Operators):

```
perl -pi -e '$_="" unless /By.unanimous.vote/ .. 1' input-files
```

Shorter solution that also uses the [`x=!!` pseudo operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897853/what-pseudo-operators-exist-in-perl-5/2897939#2897939):

```
per -pi -e '$_ x=!! (/By.unanimous.vote/ .. 1)' input-files
```

Comment: How does the flip-flop work? I read linked page but confused about meaning of `/pattern/ .. 1`. Does it go in reverse order i.e. line containing `By.unanimous.vote` to 1st line?

Answer (score 3):

Have a try with:

If you want to get rid until the last `By.unanimous.vote`

```
perl -00 -pe "s/.*By.unanimous.vote//s" inputfile > outputfile
```

If you want to get rid until the first `By.unanimous.vote`

```
perl -00 -pe "s/.*?By.unanimous.vote//s" inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: In that case use `.*?` without /g and with /s

Comment: @Qtax: You're right if OP wants to get rid until the first occurrence.

Comment: You still need /s, without it this will not work. Or does `.` follow the input record separator for its [^newline] matching?

Comment: @Qtax: `-00` defines the record separator to null so there's no needs to `/s`

Comment: @M42, apparently `.` does not care about the record separator, `perl -00 -e "print qq!foo\nbar! =~ /(.*)/"` prints `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't said whether you want to keep the `By.unanimous.vote` part, but it sounds to me like you want:

```
s/[\s\S]*?(?=By\.unanimous\.vote)//
```

Note the missing `g` flag and the lazy `*?` quantifier, because you want to stop matching once you hit that string. This should preserve `By.unanimous.vote` and everything after it. The `[\s\S]` matches newlines. In Perl, you can also do this with:

```
s/.*?(?=By\.unanimous\.vote)//s
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
perl -pi -e "$a=1 if !$a && /By\.unanimous\.vote/i; s/.*//s if !$a" *.txt
```

Should remove the lines before the matched line. If you want to remove the matching line also you can do something like:

```
perl -pi -e "$a=1 if !$a && s/.*By\.unanimous\.vote.*//is; s/.*//s if !$a" *.txt
```

Shorter versions:

```
perl -pi -e "$a++if/By\.unanimous\.vote/i;$a||s/.*//s" *.txt
perl -pi -e "$a++if s/.*By\.unanimous\.vote.*//si;$a||s/.*//s" *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using awk

```
awk '/.*By.unanimous.vote/{a=1} a==1{print}' input > output
```