# Using Perl to extract the number of matches in a string

Tags: regex, perl

How can I find out the number of disks in this string?

```
$str='disk 0_1 0_2 0_3';
```

In this `$str`, the number of disks is 3.

How can Perl output how many disks there are in this string?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
my $count = () = $str =~ /\d+_\d+/g;
```

Comment: +1, nice, I hardly understand why that works. Thought that the assignment to an empty list would reset/lose the count of elements in the original list.

Comment: @Qtax : This is the [countof operator](http://github.com/cowens/perlopref); useful when you want to count how many items you have in your list but don't want to store it in an array.

Comment: @Zaid Your link in the comment is dead.

Comment: @FailedDev : Looks like Chas needs to be notified

Comment: @FailedDev : [Chas.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/78259/chas-owens) started the `perlopref` documentation project I tried to link to and he asked [a very interesting question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897853/what-pseudo-operators-exist-in-perl-5) on SO a while ago :)

Comment: @Zaid Oo :) Interestning indeed :) +1 for the lulz :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$disk_count = scalar( split ' ', $str) - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my @result = $str=~ m/\d_\d/g;
print "Number of disks found : ", scalar(@result), "\n";
```

Comment: this answer looks the most straight forward to understand, save the output to the array, then get array account.

Comment: @brike : This solution is more or less the same as mine, except that I throw the array away.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $counter = 0;
$counter++ while ($str =~ m/\d+_\d+/g);
```

Comment: Can be done without looping as I remember, but I dont have perl in-front of me atm