# perl command line equivalent of php -E

Tags: perl, command-line

```
php -R '$count++' -E 'print "$count\n";' < somefile
```

will print the number of lines in 'somefile' (not that I would actually do this).

I'm looking to emulate the -E switch in a perl command.

```
perl -ne '$count++' -???? 'print "$count\n"' somefile
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an `END { ... }` block to add code that should be executed after the loop:

```
perl -ne '$count++; END { print "$count\n"; }' somefile
```

You can also easily put it in its own `-e` argument, if you want it more separated:

```
perl -ne '$count++;' -e 'END { print "$count\n"; }' somefile
```

See also:

- [`perlmod` - `BEGIN`, `UNITCHECK`, `CHECK`, `INIT` and `END`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2c-UNITCHECK%2c-CHECK%2c-INIT-and-END) at [perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org).

Comment: You're the only one who understood the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

TIMTOWTDI

You can use the [Eskimo Kiss](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2897853/725418) operator:

```
perl -nwE '}{ say $.' somefile
```

This operator is less magical than one thinks, as seen if we deparse the one-liner:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -nwE '}{say $.' somefile 
BEGIN { $^W = 1; }
BEGIN {
    $^H{'feature_unicode'} = q(1);
    $^H{'feature_say'} = q(1);
    $^H{'feature_state'} = q(1);
    $^H{'feature_switch'} = q(1);
}
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    ();
}
{
    say $.;
}
-e syntax OK
```

It simply tacks on an extra set of curly braces, making the following code wind up outside the implicit while loop.

Or you can check for end of file.

```
perl -nwE 'eof and say $.' somefile
```

With multiple files, you get a cumulative sum printed for each of them.

```
perl -nwE 'eof and say $.' somefile somefile somefile
10
20
30
```

You can close the file handle to get a non-cumulative count:

```
perl -nwE 'if (eof) { say $.; close ARGV }' somefile somefile somefile
10
10
10
```

Comment: @Zaid It's a nice trick, thanks for sharing it. I just realised it will not actually work with the `-p` switch, like it says in the question I linked to - only `-n`. With `-p` it will become `while (<>) { (); } { code } continue { print }`.

Answer (score 6):

This should be what you're looking for:

```
perl -nle 'END { print $. }'  notes.txt
```

Comment: Ahh, that's it.  thanks.  Thanks for the '-l' too.  I didn't know about that either.