# concatenate hash values when key is same in perl

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash
something like :

```
abc=>1
hello=>32
abc=>4
hello=>23
hello=>12
xyz=>18
```

how can we concatenate the values, whose keys are same.
So the output will be:

```
abc=>"1,4"
hello=>"23,12,32"
xyz=>"18".
```

I tried by sorting the hash by keys then checking for each key, if they are same then concatenate the value, but i am not getting that how to compare two keys in same loop.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like a key->value pairs, not a hash, since hash always have exactly one value associated with one key.

Comment: How can you have a hash with same keys? Do you mean you have an array with `key => value` pairs?

Comment: It is impossible for a Perl hash to have two elements with the same key. Please describe your underlying problem.

Comment: Yes i am wrong in putting my question, this isn't a hash but a key->value pair. i am sorry for that,

Answer (score 7):

The exact way this works depends on the real source of your data, but this program shows a way to read the information from the `DATA` filehandle to build and dump a hash.

The values of the hash are anonymous arrays that contain all the values corresponding to the same key.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;

while (<DATA>) {
  my ($k, $v) = /\w+/g;
  push @{ $data{$k} }, $v;
}

for my $k (sort keys %data) {
  printf "%s => %s\n", $k, join ',', @{ $data{$k} };
}

__DATA__
abc=>1
hello=>32
abc=>4
hello=>23
hello=>12
xyz=>18
```

**output**

```
abc => 1,4
hello => 32,23,12
xyz => 18
```

Comment: +1, didn't know you could push onto undefined reference like that.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a list with key value pairs you are talking about then you could do something like:

```
my @kv = (
    abc=>1,
    hello=>32,
    abc=>4,
    hello=>23,
    hello=>12,
    xyz=>18,
);

my %hash;

while(@kv){
    my $k = shift @kv;
    my $v = shift @kv;

    $hash{$k} = defined $hash{$k} ? "$hash{$k},$v" : $v;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my @pairs = (
    abc=>1,
    hello=>32,
    abc=>4,
    hello=>23,
    hello=>12,
    xyz=>18,
);

my %hash;

# collect
for(my $idx = 0; $idx < scalar @pairs; $idx += 2){
    my $key = $pairs[$idx];
    my $val = $pairs[$idx+1];
    push @{ $hash{$key} }, $val;
}

# print combined
while( my ($key, $val) = each %hash ){
    print "$key = ", join(',', @$val), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is unclear what you are really trying to do, I am guessing that you have a file that you need to change. In which case, a one-liner might be in order.

```
perl -lwne '
    ($k,$v) = split /=>/; 
    $data{$k} = join ",", $data{$k} // (), $v }{ 
    print "$_=>$data{$_}" for keys %data' input.txt > output.txt
```

**Output:**

```
hello=>32,23,12
abc=>1,4
xyz=>18
```

Note that the keys in the output will not be in the same order as the input. You can sort the keys if you like, but I opted not to.

Explanation:

- `-l` will remove line endings while reading, and put them back while printing
- `-n` will place a `while(<>)` loop around the program, reading the file (or STDIN) line by line.
- `//` is the [`defined-or` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or). It will return the RHS if the LHS is undefined.
- `}{` is the [eskimo kiss operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2897853/725418) which only works with the `-n` option. What it does is basically the same as an END block, it performs the following code at the end of the input.

Comment: hi TLP,
I tried running this code but this gives an error like : 
String found where operator expected at near `print "$_=>$Rhash{$_}" for keys %Rhash'`
  (Might be a runaway multi-line '' string starting on line 90)
  (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
Scalar found where operator expected near `print "$_=>$Rhash{$_}" for keys %Rhash'`.  I tried to correct it but can't, as i am not much familiar with Perl one-liner. If you think i am making some mistake or you are aware of this error so please tell me.   Thanks in advance

Comment: @rahul What is this I hear about line 90? Did you paste this into some other program file or something?