# Multiple values for a hash element in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [concatenate hash values when key is same in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899977/concatenate-hash-values-when-key-is-same-in-perl)

I want to store multiple values for a key in hash. For eg:

```
Input:
SMP00001    HMDB00641
SMP00001    HMDB00051
SMP00001    HMDB00052
SMP00003    HMDB00051
SMP00003    HMDB00517
SMP00004    HMDB00243

Output:
SMP00001: HMDB00641,HMDB00051,HMDB00052
SMP00003: HMDB00051,HMDB00517
SMP00004: HMDB00243
```

Here is the code I wrote:

```
push(@{$hash{$smp_id}},$HMDB_id);
```

When I print the content in hash the output is:

```
SMP00001 => ARRAY(0x161da40)
SMP00003 => ARRAY(0x11be28)
SMP00004 => ARRAY(0x1265c8)
```

Comment: Same question had been asked, you can check here for more detailed answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899977/concatenate-hash-values-when-key-is-same-in-perl.

Comment: Voting to close as this exact question has been asked several times before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print "$_: ", join(',', @{$hash{$_}}), "\n" for keys %hash;
```

Answer (score 2):

The values of your hashtable are array references, so you must dereference them to see the elements. That is, instead of

```
print "$key => $hash{$key}\n";
```

say

```
print "$key => @{$hash{$key}}\n";
```