# Python slice list at n and take the next x elements?

Tags: python, list, slice

I've not been able to Google this issue, I want to slice `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` at index 2 and take the next 3 elements (ie `[3,4,5]`). The notation `list[start:stop:step]` doesn't actually allow this or am I not aware of some Pythonic way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do *two* slices.

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> l[start:][:length]
[3, 4, 5]
```

It's only 3 additional characters, although it's relatively expensive, computationally, since an extra intermediate object needs to be created for the second slice operation.

(If this were Perl, `:][:` could be considered a [pseudo-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2897853/1126841).)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
>>> l[2:5]
[3, 4, 5]
```

Or more generally, if you know the start index and length of the slice

```
def sliceToLength(l, at, size):
    return l[at: at+size]

>>> sliceToLength(l, 2, 3)
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: I'm aware of this, but is there something more concise? Like PHP's [substr](http://php.net/substr)

Comment: What could be more concise than slice notation? It is literally one line, you just give the start, then calculate the end as start+len.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I thought there would be something like `l[start:length]`, `length` instead of `at+size` in the standard lib.